# RegisterClientScriptBlock - not firing

Tags: javascript, c#, registerclientscriptblock

I been looking at the `RegisterClientScriptBlock` object which runs some JavaScript code and I have been trying to use it.

I currently have

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "", "<script type=\"text/javascript\">function clearStorage() {alert('here');localStorage.clear();}</script>", false);
```

I would expect the alert to pop up when the code is hit but it never does, is the parameters correct or am I going down the wrong road?

Thanks

Chris

Comment: how is `clearStorage()` getting called?

Comment: Good spot. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "", "<script type=\"text/javascript\">function clearStorage() {alert('here');localStorage.clear();} clearStorage();</script>", false);
```